# ReuseParameterOnRefresh doesn't hide Enter Parameters screen

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My report uses `ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh`, but if I refresh the Report after the initial open, the "Enter Parameters" screen still shows.

```
reportFile.Refresh();
reportFile.SetParameterValue(0, "param0");
crystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportFile;
```

This code was written in  SAP Crystal Reports 2016. If  set the `ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh` both in code and on the Window Properties. In both cases the parameters aren't being reused. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you caching your Report in your webpage ?

Comment: It is is actually just a WinForm Application